# How to handle "temporary value dropped" error when adapting Box-based tree structure to Rc+RefCell?

Tags: rust, tree, refcell

I've created a tree with a type definition similar to:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) struct TreeBox<T> {
    root: Option<Box<NodeBox<T>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct NodeBox<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<NodeBox<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<NodeBox<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord> TreeBox<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let mut node = &mut self.root;

        while let Option::Some(current_node) = node {
            match current_node.value.cmp(&value) {
                Ordering::Less => node = &mut current_node.right,
                Ordering::Equal => return false,
                Ordering::Greater => node = &mut current_node.left,
            }
        }

        *node = Option::Some(Box::new(NodeBox {
            value,
            left: Option::None,
            right: Option::None,
        }));

        return true;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly and I'm very happy with the implementation. However I want to store a reference from each node to it's parent. After some research I found [a section in the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html?highlight=Weak#adding-a-reference-from-a-child-to-its-parent) describing an implementation using `RefCell` and `Weak` structs.

With this knowledge my plan was to update the example from above. My idea was that I could just substitute `Box<...>` with `Rc<RefCell<..>>`. My thinking was that these types are very similar in that they both store a reference to some data structure, only difference is that there can be multiple `Rc<RefCell<..>>`'s pointing to that data structure. I changed my implementation to:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    right: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord> Tree<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let mut node = &mut self.root;

        while let Option::Some(current_node) = node {
            let cmp = current_node.borrow().value.cmp(&value);
            match cmp {
                Ordering::Less => node = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().right,
                Ordering::Equal => return false,
                Ordering::Greater => node = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().left,
            };
        }

        *node = Option::Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            value,
            left: Option::None,
            right: Option::None,
        })));

        return true;
    }
}
```

However this updated example doesn't compile:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:28:47
   |
28 |                 Ordering::Less => node = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().right,
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     -
   |                                               |                             |
   |                                               |                             temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                                               |                             ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `RefMut<'_, Node<T>>`
   |                                               creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                                               a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Both examples are available on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9929b2118e2430f03035da4c65a4cf2f).

Is my example wrong, or is there something I still don't quite understand about `Rc<RefCell<_>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a few problems. The primary one is that you're trying to take references to an `Option` that contains a value whose lifetime is short because it's tied to the `borrow()` on `RefCell`. (You're also trying to `borrow_mut` while a `borrow` is in place, which will panic.) Thankfully, `Rc` makes it cheap and easy to take ownership of references to `Rc` (that's the whole point), so this problem can be solved by storing `Option`, not `&Option`, and liberally cloning the contained `Rc`. We use `Option::as_ref` to convert an `&Option<Rc<_>>` into an `Option<&Rc<_>>`, which then gets turned into a `Option<Rc<_>>` by mapping `Rc::clone` over it.

```rust
pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
    let mut node = self.root.as_ref().map(Rc::clone);

    while let Some(current_node) = node {
        let current_node = current_node.borrow();
        let cmp = current_node.value.cmp(&value);
        let new_node = match cmp {
            Ordering::Less => &current_node.left,
            Ordering::Equal => return false,
            Ordering::Greater => &current_node.right,
        };
        node = new_node.as_ref().map(Rc::clone);
    }

    let node = &mut node;
    *node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
        value,
        left: None,
        right: None,
    })));

    true
}
```

Comment: How is this the accepted answer if the code doesn't actually work?

Comment: `map(clone)` -> `cloned()`.

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães This happens. Downvote and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original answer is correct, the code in the example don't work because it forgets to add the root node.

Those are two alternatives that solves this problem:

```rust
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        //if no root, just create one
        let mut node = if let Some(root) = &self.root {
            Rc::clone(root)
        } else {
            self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                value,
                left: None,
                right: None,
            })));
            return true;
        };

        loop {
            let current_node = Rc::clone(&node);
            let mut current_node = RefCell::borrow_mut(&current_node);
            let cmp = current_node.value.cmp(&value);
            let next_node = match cmp {
                Ordering::Less => &mut current_node.left,
                Ordering::Equal => return false,
                Ordering::Greater => &mut current_node.right,
            };
            if let Some(next_node) = next_node {
                node = Rc::clone(next_node);
            } else {
                *next_node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                    value,
                    left: None,
                    right: None,
                })));

                println!("node: {:?}", node);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Recursive solution:

```rust
impl<T: Ord + fmt::Debug> Tree<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        //if no root, just create one
        if let Some(root) = &self.root {
            let mut root = RefCell::borrow_mut(&root);
            root.insert(value)
        } else {
            self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                value,
                left: None,
                right: None,
            })));
            true
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord + fmt::Debug> Node<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let node = match self.value.cmp(&value) {
            Ordering::Less => &mut self.left,
            Ordering::Equal => return false,
            Ordering::Greater => &mut self.right,
        };
        //if the node is empty, add to it, otherwise check deeper
        if let Some(node) = node {
            let mut node = RefCell::borrow_mut(node);
            node.insert(value)
        } else {
            *node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                value,
                left: None,
                right: None,
            })));
            println!("node: {:?}", node);
            true
        }
    }
}
```