# Cannot borrow as mutable, getting a mutable reference from a borrowed value

Tags: rust, immutability, mutable

I was following this other post: [Understanding Rust `Rc<RefCell<_>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957110/understanding-rust-rcrefcell) where op tried implementing a tree with Box and was successful in doing it but then tried implementing it with Rc and RefCell and found issues. The accepted answer compiles but doesn't work because it doesn't add nodes to the root. I tried updating the accepted answer a bit to try and get it to work but wasn't able to. Basically I'm trying to get mutable references in the loop and I can't because I borroed an immutable reference. But then if a borrow_mut() I get that value is a private field, so I'm assuming I can't access any properties of the contained value if it is a mutable reference?

What should I do to get this code to work?

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) struct TreeBox<T> {
    root: Option<Box<NodeBox<T>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct NodeBox<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<NodeBox<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<NodeBox<T>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord> TreeBox<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let mut node = &mut self.root;

        while let Option::Some(current_node) = node {
            match current_node.value.cmp(&value) {
                Ordering::Less => node = &mut current_node.right,
                Ordering::Equal => return false,
                Ordering::Greater => node = &mut current_node.left,
            }
        }

        *node = Option::Some(Box::new(NodeBox {
            value,
            left: Option::None,
            right: Option::None,
        }));

        return true;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    right: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T: Ord + fmt::Debug> Tree<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let mut node = &mut self.root;

        while let Some(current_node) = node {
            let current_node = current_node.borrow();
            let cmp = current_node.value.cmp(&value);
            let new_node = match cmp {
                Ordering::Less => &mut current_node.left,
                Ordering::Equal => return false,
                Ordering::Greater => &mut current_node.right,
            };
            node = new_node;
        }

        // let mut node = &mut node;
        *node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })));

        println!("node: {:?}", node);
        true
    }

}

fn main() {

    let mut tree_box = TreeBox::new();
    tree_box.insert(1);
    tree_box.insert(2);
    tree_box.insert(3);

    let mut tree = Tree::new();
    tree.insert(1);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(3);

    println!("TreeBox: {:?}", tree_box);
    println!("Tree: {:?}", tree);
}
```

Comment: Because you errorneously imported `BorrowMut` you use `BorrowMut::borrow_mut` instead of `RefCell::borrow_mut` also what do you hope to gain by using `Rc<RefCell<T>>` over `Box<T>`? This is not one of it's applications imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The accepted answer compiles but doesn't work because it doesn't add nodes to the root.

You are right, and fixing the original solution, here a version that add the root node correctly:

```rust
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        //if no root, just create one
        let mut node = if let Some(root) = &self.root {
            Rc::clone(root)
        } else {
            self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                value,
                left: None,
                right: None,
            })));
            return true;
        };

        loop {
            let current_node = Rc::clone(&node);
            let mut current_node = RefCell::borrow_mut(&current_node);
            let cmp = current_node.value.cmp(&value);
            let next_node = match cmp {
                Ordering::Less => &mut current_node.left,
                Ordering::Equal => return false,
                Ordering::Greater => &mut current_node.right,
            };
            if let Some(next_node) = next_node {
                node = Rc::clone(next_node);
            } else {
                *next_node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                    value,
                    left: None,
                    right: None,
                })));

                println!("node: {:?}", node);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

> Basically I'm trying to get mutable references in the loop and I can't because I borroed an immutable reference.

The problem is slightly different. what happens is that you can't walk this `Rc<RefCell>` tree, at least not interactively like this, because the "borrow" of such structures need to be keep while you are working with it. And your implementation releases the "borrow" after each loop.

> But then if a borrow_mut() I get that value is a private field, so I'm
> assuming I can't access any properties of the contained value if it is
> a mutable reference?

Not really, what is happening here is that you are not calling the function `RefCell::borrow_mut` that returns a `RefMut<Node>`, you are in fact calling `<Rc as BorrowMut>::borrow_mut` that returns `&mut RefMut<...>`. And by accessing the `value` you are trying the access the private field `value` from `RefCell`, not `Node`.

Notice that in my implementation I explicitly called `RefCell::borrow_mut`, that fixes this issue.

Comment: I think this answer should be moved to the original question.

Comment: Agreed, especially since the existing question there is better posed for other readers but the existing answer is deficient.

Comment: I understand your solution of passing owned instances of Rc around through loop iterations instead of mutable references, but is it the case that I can't borrow mutable through iterations? The Box implementation of the original post does just that. Why does that work?

Comment: Holding a mutable reference is very different from using `RefCell::borrow_mut`. That's is because you can only access the data inside a RefCell if you are holding the borrowed value (`Ref/RefMut`) in a variable, you could do that if instead of a loop, you had a recursive call.

Comment: But Im cloning `&mut current_node.left` and all of a sudden im able to pass this Rc object to the next iteration, even though the previous borrow_mut got dropped. How come I can keep a reference in Rc of a previous borrow_mut? Why when RefMut gets dropped we don't lose access to the object inside Rc?

Comment: You can't, your code don't compile, the compiler specifically error on this part of the code with `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

Comment: Im actually asking why does your code work? Why can you keep a reference in Rc but not in a variable? What's the difference?

Comment: I simply don't  get any references inside the loop that the outlive the loop, the reference `current_node.left` is cloned with Rc, and is released before the end of the loop.